# Thingsboard service stops on Windows

Tags: thingsboard

We installed Thingsboard on Windows 10 Pro machine.We follow this guide -> https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/windows/

After few minutes, the service stop unexpectedly.

At the end of log we have this error:

```
2020-02-28 16:24:38,434 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rpcController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'actorService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultActorService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'actorContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'actorSystemContext': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jsSandbox'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'nashornJsInvokeService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/ClassFilter
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - refrain from posting links and, instead, include the relevant code.

Comment: Thank you for the comment Saucy, i'll follow the instructions in the future.